# Override method for each in parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have the following classes:

```
enum class Group
{
    A,
    B
};

template <Group G>
class AbstractGroupVisitor;

template <Group G>
class GroupMessage;

class AbstractMessageVisitor;

class AbstractMessage
{
public:
    virtual void accept(AbstractMessageVisitor& visitor) = 0;
};

class AbstractMessageVisitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(GroupMessage<Group::A>& msg) = 0;
    virtual void visit(GroupMessage<Group::B>& msg) = 0;
    //A pure virtual method for each item in the Group enum
};

template <Group G>
class GroupMessage:
    public AbstractMessage
{
public:
    void accept(AbstractMessageVisitor& visitor) final { visitor.visit(*this); }

    virtual void accept(AbstractGroupVisitor<G>& visitor) = 0;
};
```

Is there a way I can write a CRTP template like the following

```
template <Group... Gs>
class GroupsVisitor;
```

That would be able to:

1. Inherit from `AbstractMessageVisitor`
2. Inherit from `AbstractGroupVisitor` for every Group in `Gs`
3. Implement the `visit` method from `AbstractMessageVisitor` for every Group in `Gs`

If I were to write a class manually, it would look like:

```
class MyVisitor:
    public AbstractMessageVisitor,
    public AbstractGroupVisitor<Group::A>,
    public AbstractGroupVisitor<Group::B>
{
public:
    void visit(GroupMessage<Group::A>& msg) final { msg.accept(static_cast<AbstractGroupVisitor<Group::A>&>(*this)); }
    void visit(GroupMessage<Group::B>& msg) final { msg.accept(static_cast<AbstractGroupVisitor<Group::B>&>(*this)); }
};
```

As a side note, I am doing this in order to mimic some of the features of virtual inheritance without the overhead of thunks and excess tables for every method in the final class.

Comment: "*mimic some of the features of virtual inheritance*" What feature is being mimic'd here? There can be no runtime polymorphism, as the message encodes the type it works with as a template parameter. You could use type erasure, but you could use type erasure in `MyVisitor` too.

Comment: "mimic some of the features of virtual inheritance" Where's the diamond? There is no diamond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do some recursion based on template specialization of `GroupsVisitor`. The following code compiles for me:

```
template <Group... Gs>
class GroupsVisitor;

template <>
class GroupsVisitor<> : public AbstractMessageVisitor {};

template <Group First, Group ... Rest>
class GroupsVisitor<First, Rest...> : public AbstractGroupVisitor<First>, public GroupsVisitor<Rest...> {
public:
  void visit(GroupMessage<First>& msg) final {
    msg.accept(static_cast<AbstractGroupVisitor<First>&>(*this));
  }
};

class MyVisitor : public GroupsVisitor<Group::A, Group::B> {
};

MyVisitor myVisitor;
```

but I had to change `AbstractGroupVisitor` from being forward declared to have a class body:

```
template <Group G>
class AbstractGroupVisitor {};
```

Otherwise, the compiler complains about "incomplete type".